What type of distribution is this? Log-normal, Weibull, Gamma, or something else?
I am trying to test this against various similar looking distributions to find the one which fits best or is least likely to match by random chance. These look log normal, but my attempts to convert them to a CDF and test for that seem to indicate most likely they are not, what would be the correct procedure to do this in either Excel, Python, or anything else, does this look like it could be gamma distributions or something else? So far I have tried mass testing this in python with mixed p-values, none of which reached any high statistical significance.

0.017395254
0.580788701
2.244034191
7.116155325
19.0835451
44.22988025
90.1234036
163.7739646
268.7945222
403.0639053
558.1949644
721.2332237
877.8496588
1015.64494
1126.371677
1206.604403
1257.103971
1281.485766
1284.787505
1272.313357
1248.889279
1218.498567
1184.193139
1148.168015
1111.910213
1076.364372
1042.083872
1009.35445
978.2880808
948.890246
921.1057462
894.8484136
870.0194081
846.5178232
824.246362
803.1140138
783.037009
763.9388577
745.7499466
728.4069606
711.8522682
696.0333321
680.9021736
666.4148936
652.53125
639.2142857
626.43
614.1470588
602.3365385
590.9716981
580.0277778
569.4818182
559.3125
549.5
540.0258621
530.8728814
522.025
513.4672131
505.1854839
497.1666667
489.3984375
481.8692308
474.5681818
467.4850746
460.6102941
453.9347826
447.45
441.1478873
435.0208333
429.0616438
423.2635135
417.62
412.125
406.7727273
401.5576923
396.4746835
391.51875
386.6851852
381.9695122
377.3674699
372.875
368.4882353
364.2034884
360.0172414
355.9261364
351.9269663
348.0166667
344.1923077
340.451087
336.7903226
333.2074468
329.7
326.265625
322.9020619
319.6071429
316.3787879


Is the data you provided for only 1 of these curves, or both? If so, how to parse it between the 2 curves?

Why do you think that these numbers are probability densities? Also, if those are the densities then what are the support values?

I included 1 curve, these are likely Probability densities because they are explicitly from an economic simulation that is supposed to produce a population curve of businesses at various sizes in an economy, the corresponding values would be various, as this will be various interpretations of business size and etc., but it's not particularly important because they are an unrelated index of something like larger businesses towards the left end of the graph, and smaller businesses towards the right end of the graph, but the index simply goes from 1 to 96 in this case


Why would you expect the output of the simulation follow any of the distributions you suggested? 2. Why would it follow any simple-form distribution with a name?  3. If you can obtain simulated values from the distribution, why do you need a specific distribution name/formula? What do you need that you can't achieve with simulations?



These don't look like random values drawn independently from some distribution, they seem too regular. Are  they obtained from some smooth curve (or perhaps a summary like a histogram( that has been fitted to simulated values instead? 2. It's got a distinct "kink" at around the 10th percentiles sort of like it's two distinct distributions joined together. It won't fit any of the "simple" smooth distributions. 3. While the distribution is right skewed, the upper tail is very short, almost as if the top end is truncated.


not that it particularly is relevant to the discussion, but there are other economics papers mentioning that certain things in economics follow certain distributions, and by matching this distribution to those, I can confirm these other papers' results. That's interesting you see it as possibly 2 distributions? What is your guess as to what they are? An you tried to fit it to common distributions?

regarding how they are obtained, the economy simulation I made is basically a spreadsheet that has a complex method to calculate risk and rate of return for businesses, given certain GDP inputs across an economy, it's kind of like an equation but as a large piece of code with many steps that likely could be made into a simpler equation, but it's a regular process with no random values generation per say

yes the top curve is truncated, but in theory would go on to 0 as the lower curve does, I included the top curve as data because any set of values from any common distribution should be able to reverse engineer the original

The data clearly cannot be from any of the distributions you mention. Even the most cursory of examinations makes that clear. Nor would any of the approximately 200 named distributions on wikipedia suffice.

what details made you determine that?
